# Extract key-pair value in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, key-value, hashicorp-vault

I have this jenkinsfile in which I am getting the value from Hashicorp vault. The secrets are in key-value pair. I have stored that in secret_key variable. How do I extract the value from it

```
node {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'VaultTokenCredentialBinding', 
                      addrVariable: 'VAULT_ADDR', 
                      credentialsId: 'token', 
                      tokenVariable: 'VAULT_TOKEN', 
                      vaultAddr: 'http://ip:8200']]) {
        script{
            secret_key = sh (
                        script: 'vault kv get -format json -field=data kv/secret', 
                        returnStdout: true
                        )
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
+ vault kv get -format json -field=data kv/secret
{
  "password": "admin",
  "username": "admin"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vault CLI returns a JSON String to `stdout`, so you can parse it in your pipeline accordingly with the `readJSON` step method:

```
secretKeyMap = readJSON(text: secret_key)
```

Afterwards, the `readJSON` method returns a Map type converted from the JSON String, so you can also parse that accordingly with the proper syntax:

```
secretKeyMap['password'] // admin
secretKeyMap['username'] // admin
secretKeyMap.password // admin
secretKeyMap.username // admin
```